# Can Bind cache a response packet, instead of reconstructing from cached data?

Tags: domain-name-system, performance, cache

Is it possible to cache the response packets from Bind instead of reconstructing them everytime from cached data? If not, is there any DNS server software that would do this, or are we getting into the custom area? We are doing 50k/Qps and things are starting to get interesting (we're a DNS provider).

Comment: So you need to squeeze as many responses per second as possible out of just one machine, and you've measured things and found out that it's packet assembly that's your hot spot?

Comment: You got it pontiac!

Comment: Then I'm afraid I have no suggestion. The setups I've seen with serious load on them (ccTLD registries) have just added more machines.